# What exactly is 'e' and what does e.code() or e.read() do?

Tags: python, urllib2

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    response = json.loads(e.read())
    return error(e.code(),response['errors'][0]['message'])
response = json.loads(response.read())
if 'errors' in response:
    return error(response['ErrorCode'],response['Error'])
```

Here is the piece of code I am working with and you can help me out referring to this piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is the caught exception, here an instance of the `urllib2.URLError` class or a subclass thereof. The code expects that instance to define the `e.read()` and `e.code()` methods.

However, it has some errors. It actually assumes it is catching the [`urllib2.HTTPError` exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError), a subclass of `URLError`. The exception handler certainly will catch such exceptions, but it could also be the base `URLError`, in which case there won't be an `e.read()` method! It also tries to call [`HTTPError.code`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError.code), which is not a method but an attribute.

The `HTTPError` exception is thrown for HTTP error codes, so only when there was a response from the server. `e.read()` lets you read the response body from the socket, and `e.code` is the HTTP code the server responded with. From the documentation:

> Though being an exception (a subclass of `URLError`), an `HTTPError` can also function as a non-exceptional file-like return value (the same thing that `urlopen()` returns). This is useful when handling exotic HTTP errors, such as requests for authentication.

For the code to work in all cases, it would have to be corrected to:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    response = json.loads(e.read())
    return error(e.code, response['errors'][0]['message'])
```

perhaps with an additional `except urllib2.URLError as e:` block to handle errors that don't involve a HTTP response.

Comment: is `response['errors'][0]['message']` unique to my code or does it serve any special function? Can it/should it be replaced by something like e.message() or e.reason()?

Comment: @deepanshpahwa: note that that is loaded from the response body. It is unique to the *HTTP server the code contacts*. `e.read()` reads the server response, which is then decoded as a JSON document. That is expected to result in a dictionary with a `'errors'` key that is a list.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.
Have a great day.